# C++ alphabetical build order

Tags: c++, build

Here's a snippet from my build output in Visual Studio 2010:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Release_PG 
>   Win32 ------ 1>icl : warning #10187: PGOPTI instrumentation disables
>   multifile optimizations 1>icl : warning #10188: PGOPTI instrumentation
>   disables IP optimizations 
>   
> 1>  !BasketNovel.cpp 1>  Compiling
>   precompiled.h - this should happen just once per project. 1>   1> 
>   Compiling BasketNovel.h. 1>
>   
> 1>  Camera.cpp 1>  Compiling
>   precompiled.h - this should happen just once per project. 1>   1> 
>   Compiling BasketNovel.h. 1>
>   
> 1>  Console.cpp 1>  Compiling
>   precompiled.h - this should happen just once per project. 1>   1> 
>   Compiling BasketNovel.h. 1>
>   
> 1>  Entity.cpp 1>  Compiling
>   precompiled.h - this should happen just once per project. 1>   1> 
>   Compiling BasketNovel.h. 1>
>   
> 1>  Font.cpp

From what I see, the compiler's building my .cpp files in alphabetical order. I'm not really familiar with build concepts. Is this a normal behaviour?

Note: I am using the Intel C++ compiler.

Comment: @aleguna I'm looking more for an answer that explains why this is happening and if it is indeed normal behaviour.

Comment: It's happening just because Visual Studio developers designed the build system to work this way. It's not 'normal' or 'not normal' it's just the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of compilation is not really important. The important step that builds your end-product (executable, library, etc) is the linking step, where the pieces from the compilation step will be linked together.

Comment: Thanks for making that point. I'll start looking more into linking concepts.

Comment: You can examine all steps from code to end product. An example would be http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html. Or Google 'compiler steps'.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The diagram neatly illustrates the various concepts I was looking for.

Comment: btw, does this mean that if a .cpp file doesn't have it's own corresponding header file it would slow down building time?

Comment: First, there is no such thing as 'corresponding header'. You need to explicitly `#include` all the headers you require. Any directive that starts with a `#` is handled by the pre-processor and therefore does not affect the compile time.